# One Regular Expression to validate Zip code not working

Tags: java, regex

Below regex (see code snippet) will satisfy all following four conditions:

- 12345
- 12345-6789
- 12345_6789
- 12345 1234

I need to include a 5th condition which is 123456789 (hence, 9 digits only, no space) I've tried to change the current regex to this ^[0-9]{5}(_|-|\s){0,1}|[0-9]{4} but this doesn't work

```
public static boolean isZipCodeValid(String zipcode) {
    return zipcode.matches("^\\d{5}(?:[-_\\s]\\d{4})?$");
}
```

Comment: You already know you may use `{0,1}` to match 1 or 0 occurrences. Why not use it in your current regex? Or its equivalent, `?`? `[-_\\s]` => `[-_\\s]?`

Comment: `zipcode.matches("\\d{5}([-_\\s]?\\d{4})?");`

Comment: @JoopEggen the`?` after the character class is missing: `zipcode.matches("\\d{5}([-_\\s]?\\d{4})?");` - your expression is basically the same as the OP's.

Comment: Yes, I checked all bullets, but not the next addition. Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't have a `|` there:

```
^[0-9]{5}(_|-|\s){0,1}|[0-9]{4}
                      ^
                    here!
```

Delete that and everything should work.

With that `|` being there, it means that matching `[0-9]{4}` is an alternative. So it will *either* match 5 digits or 4. That's why you end up with 2 matches.

Comment: If I try with 12345-6789 I will still endup with two matches. That's no good.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Did you delete the |? @user2342259

Comment: had to go back again to this regex and came across your last replay, spot on. That's the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
^\\d{5}(?:[-_\\s]?\\d{4})?$
```

It has been tested on [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to break down your expression and it should become easier to see:

1. always 5 digits (probably the first not being 0),
2. a group of 4 digits preceded by either nothing or one of 3 characters.

If you translate that to regex you should get something like (I included the non-0 first digit as well):

1. `[1-9]\d{4}`
2. `(x\d{4})?` - that's the optional (`?`) group (`(...)`) with `x` being a placeholder. Now translate "either nothing or one of a 3 characters" into an expression and you get `[-_ ]?`. (Note that I replaced `\s` with a space because `\s` includes tabs and other whitespace.

If you take that all to gether you get `[1-9]\d{4}([-_ ]?\d{4})?`.

Side note: `\d` matches other digits as well, e.g. arabic ones. You might want to use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a 2nd method which validate against 9 digits only so somewhere in my code I do something like below. Is not the most elegant way but it does what is supposed to...

```
      if(!isUsaZipCodeValid(bo.getZipCode())){
                                            if((isValidDigit9Only(bo.getZipCode()))){
                                                //do nothing
                                            } else {
                                                errors.add("zipCode", new ActionMessage("error.label.zipcode.usa.digits.only"));
                                            }
                                        }


//and these are the two methods.

public static boolean isUsaZipCodeValid(String zipcode){
      /*Below regex will satisfy all three condtions for zip-code. E.g-
        12345
        12345-6789
        12345_6789
        12345 1234
        */
        return zipcode.matches("^\\d{5}(?:[-_\\s]\\d{4})?$");
    }

    public static boolean isValidDigit9Only(String zipcode){
      /*Below regex will satisfy the below condition for the for zip-code. E.g-
        123456789
        */
        return zipcode.matches("[0-9]{9}");
    }
```